# Merge nested lists inside list of lists

Tags: python, list

I have a very huge list of the format:

```
a = [[[5],[3]],[[4],[5]],[[6],[7]]]
```

I want go get each element of my list out of innermost list. Output should be:

```
output = [[5,3],[4,5],[6,7]]
```

I tried some methods like `reduce(operator.concat, a))` , `sum(b, []))` and `reduce(lambda x,y: x+y,a)`. But they didn't generate what I want. I have a large data and I don't want to use a for loop if possible. Do you know another option for this?

Comment: I cant edit, I cant close. What can I do for this post, I need your advice @wovano

Comment: As far as I know, you still can edit the question. I reverted your last edit because it didn't improve the question: the content you added should not be included in the question. For questions about how the site works, visit the Help Center or use the meta site instead. Deleting is not possible since other people already spent time on answering your question. If your question is answered, you can just leave it like this.

Comment: I see but since the question is duplicated, I can not delete it. Changing/editing the question will give me once again a question duplicated in better writing... I can not ask questions because of these kinds of my mistakes and I try to handle but it seems that it will be very hard...

Comment: You cannot delete it because the question already has upvoted answers. The fact that is's a duplicate does not matter. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting your next question to avoid this kind of stuff. Good luck in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do:

```
a = [[x[0][0], x[1][0]] for x in a]
```

This assumes that there always only 2 elements in each list.

A generic solution would be:

```
a = [[y[0] for y in x] for x in a]
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `itertools.chain` with *list comprehension* as:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> a = [[[5],[3]],[[4],[5]],[[6],[7]]]

>>> [list(chain(*l)) for l in a]
[[5, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7]]
```

Refer ["itertools.chain()" documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Elegant solution has already been pointed out by @moinuddin-quadri. Thought I will add some variety. It is minimal but there is another way.

It can also be solved by chain.from_iterable [function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable), although the solution will read longer. chain.from_iterable is an alternate constructor for chain.

```py
from itertools import chain

a = [[[1],[2]],[[3],[4],[5]],[[6],[7]],[[8],[9],[10],[11]]]

list(map(list,map(chain.from_iterable, a)))
```

This gives

```py
[[1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11]]
```

Both methods are almost comparable in time taken as seen below.

```py
from itertools import chain
import timeit
a = [[[1],[2]],[[3],[4],[5]],[[6],[7]],[[8],[9],[10],[11]]]

def Chain(a):
    [list(chain(*l)) for l in a]

def Chain_From_Iterable(a):
    list(map(list,map(chain.from_iterable, a)))

print("From chain method: ", timeit.timeit("Chain(a)", number=1000000, globals=globals()))
print("From chain.from_iterable method: ", timeit.timeit("Chain_From_Iterable(a)", number=1000000, globals=globals()))
```

```py
From chain method:  3.0528709329992125
From chain.from_iterable method:  2.7632316279996303
```

Following is the output for both of them

Answer (score 1):

Flatten each element:

```py
a = [[[5],[3]],[[4],[5]],[[6],[7]]]

output = [[item for subsublist in sublist for item in subsublist] for sublist in a]
```

Answer (score 1):

if I'm understanding your issue properly then the following solution should work.

```
from functools import reduce
import operator

starting_list = [[[5],[3]],[[4],[5]],[[6]]]
final_list = list(map(lambda x: reduce(operator.concat, x),starting_list))
print(final_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
from itertools import chain, starmap
from operator import concat
xss = [[[5],[3]],[[4],[5]],[[6],[7]]]

def star(f):
  return lambda xs: f(*xs)

print(list(map(star(concat), xss)))
print(list(starmap(concat, xss)))
print([concat(*xs) for xs in xss])
print([list(chain(*xs)) for xs in xss])
```